# Can't run script from my own package

Tags: command-line, bash, package-management, scripts, dpkg

I have created a simple package using this [guide](http://www.king-foo.com/2011/11/creating-debianubuntu-deb-packages/), but I can't run the script inside it.

There is a folder named `mypack`, which includes `/usr/bin/myscript.sh` with some command in it (let's say it just echoes a message like "Hello World"), and a folder named `DEBIAN` with a `control` file with this text inside:

```
Package: mypack
Version: 1.0-1
Maintainer: Alex
Architecture: all
Section: misc
Description: echo me
```

I built and installed it using `dpkg-deb --build mypack`; `dpkg -i mypack.deb` as the guide says.

Finally, when I wanted to run the script script to see if it is works, I could not. I have tried:

1. `myscript` (returns `myscript: command not found`)
2. `myscript.sh` (returns `bash: /usr/bin/myscript.sh: Permission denied`)
3. `sudo myscript.sh` (returns `sudo: myscript.sh: command not found`)
4. `mypack myscript` and `mypack myscript.sh` (both return `mypack: command not found`)

How can I execute it then, so it actually works, or am I missing some important steps, which doesn't let me run the script?

Comment: Does your script have the executable bit set? What is the output of `ls -la /usr/bin/myscript.sh`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your script isn't set as executable; just like a script *not* installed by packaging, you need to make sure it has the executable bit set.

You have two options:

1. When creating the package, make sure that your script has the executable bit set *before* creating the package, by running this in your work directory *Before* building the package:

   ```
   chmod +x /path/to/script.sh
   ```

***OR...***

2. Use the `postinst` script for your package to set the executable bit *after* installation.  Add a command to the `.postinst` script similar to the following:

   ```
   chmod +x /usr/bin/myscript.sh
   ```

For some of my things, I use both methods *just* to make sure it sets things as executable.  That introduces headaches sometimes, but it's better to *make sure* than not make sure.  At least, in my opinion.

---

As for the script not being able to be executed as `myscript`, that's because `myscript` and `myscript.sh` are **different objects**.

If you want that, do the following in your `.postinst` script for your package:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/myscript.sh /usr/bin/myscript
```

... and then assuming you fix the executable bit problem, it should then 'just work' for both of the versions you were trying, both `myscript.sh` and `myscript`.

***HOWEVER*** the proper way to do this is, instead, to just package the script as `myscript` and not include the shell extension.  You should then include a shebang line at the beginning (`#!`) indicating the interpreter to use.  Since `.sh` could be anything.  Then, set up the package to just install `myscript`.  As muru stated, you should avoid making links in your postinst, but it's up to you what you want to do.  There's many *different* ways to achieve your goal, but not really much strict guidance in the documentation for packaging.

Comment: Is it this `postinst` or `.postinst`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen A plain `postinst` if the source package only creates one binary package, or `<packagename>.postinst` if multiple binary packages are created.

Comment: None of these should be done in the postinst, IMO. File permissions and links should be part of the package, unless they cannot be (for example, if the link is to somewhere in `/usr/local`, or part of the alternatives system). Otherwise you have to take care in your postrm to remove the links.